# In Spark, how to do One Hot Encoding for top N frequent values only?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, one-hot-encoding

Let, in my dataframe df, I have a column `my_category` in which I have different values, and I can view the value counts using:

```
df.groupBy("my_category").count().show()

value   count
a    197
b    166
c    210
d      5
e      2
f      9
g      3
```

Now, I'd like to apply One Hot Encoding (OHE) on this column, but for the top `N` frequent values only (say `N = 3`), and put all the rest infrequent values in a dummy column (say, "default"). E.g., the output should be something like:

```
a  b  c  default
0  0  1  0
1  0  0  0
0  1  0  0
1  0  0  0
...
0  0  0  1
0  0  0  1
...
```

**How do I do this in Spark/Scala?**

Note:
I know how to do this in Python, e.g., by first building a frequent-based dictionary for each unique value, and then create the OHE vector by examining the values one by one, putting the infrequent ones in a "default" column.

Answer (score 1):

A custom function could be written as, to apply One Hot Encoding (OHE) on a particular column, for the top N frequent values only (say N = 3).

It is relatively similar to Python, 1) Building a top n frequent-based Dataframe/Dictionary. 2) Pivot the top n frequent Dataframe i.e create the OHE vector. 3) Left join the given Dataframe and pivoted Dataframe, replace null with 0 i.e the default OHE vector.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, lit, when}
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column

import spark.implicits._
val df = spark
  .sparkContext
  .parallelize(Seq("a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "a", "b", "f", "a", "g", "a", "b", "c", "a", "d", "e", "f", "a", "b", "g", "b", "c", "f", "a", "b", "c"))
  .toDF("value")

val oheEncodedDF = oheEncoding(df, "value", 3)


def oheEncoding(df: DataFrame, colName: String, n: Int): DataFrame = {
  df.createOrReplaceTempView("data")
  val topNDF = spark.sql(s"select $colName, count(*) as count from data group by $colName order by count desc limit $n")

  val pivotTopNDF = topNDF
    .groupBy(colName)
    .pivot(colName)
    .count()
    .withColumn("default", lit(1))

  val joinedTopNDF = df.join(pivotTopNDF, Seq(colName), "left").drop(colName)

  val oheEncodedDF = joinedTopNDF
    .na.fill(0, joinedTopNDF.columns)
    .withColumn("default", flip(col("default")))

   oheEncodedDF
}

def flip(col: Column): Column = when(col === 1, lit(0)).otherwise(lit(1))
```

Comment: A related question below:

Comment: I have n columns on which I apply the regular OHE then use VectorAssembler, as:
`val s1 = new StringIndexer()... // n such sIndexers
val fE = new OneHotEncoderEstimator().setInputCols(Array(s1.getOutputCol), ...).setOutputCols(Array("enc_s1", ... ))
val vE = new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(fE.getOutputCols)...`
Now, how to extend your OHE TopN() as part of my pipeline? My desired oheEncodingTopN() cannot refer to the "actual" dataframe, since it would be a part of the pipeline (to apply on train/test).
Extending the original OneHotEncoderEstimator.scala? Any other options?

Comment: @YaleBD I am not sure what exactly are you trying to do, however it could be possible somehow to invoke the oheEncodingTopN().

Comment: I understand ... basically I'm trying to build a vectorAssembler so that it can ingest the output from your custom OneHotEncoder.
My desired oheEncodingTopN() cannot refer to the "actual" dataframe (as it was, in your function), since it would be a part of the pipeline (to apply on trainData/testData). Hence, **I'm looking for a solution that should work as an individual stage in my pipeline**, rather than a function that operates on the data directly. I tried to explain it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60423784/spark-ml-insert-fit-custom-onehotencoder-into-a-pipeline

Comment: @YaleBD oh now I could relate, I will have a look.